# How to detect a disconnection when using Server-sent events on ASP.NET CORE?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

We are writing c# code in **asp.net core** webapi for SSE (server sent events), there we wanted to know if a client closes the connection how to determine and close it from server side

here is code snippet

```
Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";
while (true)
{
  Response.Write(string.Format("data: {0}\n\n", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
  Response.Flush();

  if ([condition to detect client has closed the connection])
  {
    break;
  }
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: You may upvote the accepted answer as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be following code would be useful for you:

```
if (Response.IsClientConnected == false)
{
    break;
}
```

If it is not working you could try this:

```
if (HttpContext.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested == true)
{
    break;
}
```

Comment: HttpContext.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested == true  -- worked